# How do I get the next order number for an Ext JS Grid?

Tags: extjs

I have an order number on an Ext JS Grid. Grid rows are sorted by that order number. I have a button that opens a from window to add new rows to grid. My question is: How do I get the biggest order number from that grid. Then get it in the form and add 1 for it.

Comment: Require more specific? do you require the last record index id? biggest order number value in that grid view (assume that one column with header order numder)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is, the next number is the count of items in the store... `grid.getStore().getCount()`

or if you have a paginated remote store, it can be `grid.getStore().getTotalCount()`

That is if the backend provides a total parameter...